# Id's not updating when using EntityFramework code-first

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

after an earlier question i'm stil struggling with EF Code-First;

I have 3 (in this example, in practice there are more) where 1 table uses multiple Id's for accessing other tables.

I have 2 problems

1: the Id's for shipping and delivery aren't set (remain '0') when saving to the database. 
2: when using DBMigrations an index is created twice for the RecordId

```
.Index(t => t.RecordId),
.Index(t => t.RecordId);
```

code example:

Record Class:

```
public class Record
{
    public Record()
    {
        Shipping = new Shipping();
        Delivery = new Delivery();
    }

    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public int ShippingId { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Shipping Shipping { get; set; }
    public virtual Delivery Delivery { get; set; }
}
```

Shipping Class:

```
public class Shipping
{
    public int ShippingId { get; set; }
    public string ShippingName { get; set; }

    public virtual Record Record { get; set; }
}
```

Delivery Class:

```
public class Delivery
{
    public int DeliveryId { get; set; }
    public String DeliveryText { get; set; }

    public virtual Record Record { get; set; }
}
```

context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Shipping> Shippings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Delivery> Deliveries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.Shipping)
            .WithRequiredDependent(x => x.Record)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.Delivery)
            .WithRequiredDependent(x => x.Record)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Main program (method):

```
using (Context context = new Context())
      {
            var model = context.Records.Create();
            var shipping = model.Shipping;
            shipping.ShippingName = "TestContext";
            var delivery = model.Delivery;
            delivery.DeliveryText = "customText";
            context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Added;
            context.SaveChanges();
      }
```

Main program (second try)

```
using (Context context = new Context())
      {               
            var model = context.Records.Create();
            model.Shipping = context.Shippings.Create();
            var shipping = model.Shipping;
            shipping.ShippingName = "TestContext";
            model.Delivery = context.Deliveries.Create();
            var delivery = model.Delivery;
            delivery.DeliveryText = "customText";
            context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Added;
            context.SaveChanges();
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO avoid the extra index, don't specify the key fields in your record class.
To get the default Identity behaviour name the key fields Id

```
public class Record
{
    public Record()
    {
        Shipping = new Shipping();
        Delivery = new Delivery();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Shipping Shipping { get; set; }
    public virtual Delivery Delivery { get; set; }
}
```